# Prove the following geometric result.

Tags: geometry

> A quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in a circle $S$ and $A, B, C, D$ are the points of contact with S of another quadrilateral which is circumscribed about $S$. If this quadrilateral is also cyclic, prove that: $AB^2 +CD^2= BC^2 +AD^2$

This question has been bothering me for a long time. I'm not able to start with any significant progress. I drew the diagram and tried to use the fact that the circumradius of the smaller quadrilateral and the inradius of the bigger quadrilateral. I've run out of ideas. Would someone please help me to prove this relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B'$ be the perpendicular projection of $B$ to $AC$, $F'$ the perpendicular projection of $D$ to $AC$.
Then $$AB^2+CD^2=AB'^2+B'B^2+CD'^2+D'D^2$$
and
$$BC^2+AD^2=CB'^2+B'B^2+AD'^2+D'D^2,$$
so what you want to show is equivalent to 
$$ AB'^2+CD'^2=AD'^2+CB'^2.$$
This again is equivalent to  $B'=D'$. In other words, try to show that $AC\perp BD$.

Comment: Here let's how the last line is done.    If the larger quadrilateral is cyclic then two opposing angles are supplementary, let us say the vertices beyond sides $AB$ and $CD$ of the original quadrilateral.  Then the arcs subended by $AB$ and $CD$ are supplementary to the selected vertex angles of the larger quadrilateral which forces them to be supplementary to each other.  When $AC$ and $BD$ are drawn, they intersect to make angles measuring half the latter 180° arc sum.